# REST APIs : Should HEAD always be deterministic with respect to GET?

Tags: rest, get, head

I recently found a REST api which didn't support HEAD (i.e. Method not supported) but that supported GET for a particular URI.

- Should HEAD always be supported in REST clients?
- Or are there valid reasons to support GET without supporting HEAD?

My initial thought:  HEAD should probably always return the exact same header as GET *except* in cases where there is a non trivial cost to calculating Header information (i.e. a computationally expensive request).In which case, HEAD might not be supported to discourage trivial use of the REST API.